# Why does Kate not work with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: qt, kate

I use Ubuntu 20.04.1.; Kate 20.04.0  was installed with `sudo snap install kate`

When I start Kate I get first the message
`Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket`
and then pages of error messages.

Any hint how to get out of this mess?

alex

Answer (score 5):

First remove the SNAP package, then install the apt version.

```
$ sudo snap remove kate
...
$ sudo apt install kate
...
$ kate --version
kate 19.12.3
```

This might not be the latest version, but it sure works (20.04)

*To me snap packages are a nuisance due to not having "sane" security settings provided with/inside them, and most of all NOT adjusted to a home user's needs.*

Comment: But wouldn't this install a mountain of KDE dependencies?

Comment: Unavoidable, with snap too.

Comment: FWIW; my `/` resides on a 256GB SSD, all of it, including kate and KDE, sums up to 12.4GB of data; That is 0.0124 TB - not very much, despite numerous fun and useful packages being present. 230 of 244.5 GB available.  *(Hit the windows key and type `Disk Usage Analysator` to check yours)*

Comment: The disk usage side is convincing enough indeed; but I'm also concerned about how many of those extra / otherwise redundant modules are loaded along with the Gnome desktop, like, impact on RAM usage, and a general impact on the system's stability. Is there such a thread that explores this? I love Kate; I had positive experiences with it (from an earlier time in my life). But these aforementioned concerns kept me from installing it...

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It worked.